# Why is the simple past form "did" used here? In other words, is it still clear, grammatical and idiomatic if present simple tense is used?

Tags: tense

It sounds like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/rEnMEDo8Nzw?t=320) (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)

> if you did like this video
>   give it a thumbs up

I guess the reason that the presenter uses "did like" is to emphasize "like".

The quesiton is,

Why is the simple past form "did" an appropriate tense here?

In other words, is it still clear, grammatical and idiomatic if present simple tense is used?

> if you **do like** this video give it a thumbs up

or simply

> if you **like** this video give it a thumbs up

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.grammaring.com/the-auxiliary-did-for-emphasis).

Comment: The past tense is used because the viewer has just finished watching the video.

Comment: The simple present (i.e., just the present tense form without an auxiliary) is sometimes used for a continuing action or state.

Answer (score 1):

She is saying:

> If you **did** like this video give it a thumbs up.

The word "did" is a little redundant - normally, people would just say:

> If you *liked* this video...

This would put the correct past tense on it, as the video is over and viewers should have made their minds up whether they liked it or not.

However, it is quite common in business to say things like:

> If you liked it, tell your friends; if you didn't like it, tell us.

Businesses say things like this to try and control or stop the spread of negative feedback - they want people who are happy to spread the word and people who are not to come and talk to them so they can fix things.

The girl in the video puts a lot of emphasis on the word "*did*", so I think by doing so she is trying to put a positive spin on it - she probably doesn't want people who *didn't* like it to click 'thumbs down' - so she may be over-emphasising this to draw out only those who liked it to take action.